# Angular 6 - How to set autofocus to next row of first td in table

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on BarCode scanning in Angular 6 Project

I have created HTML table. When user scan barcode in First "td" of table then i am creating new row in table. 
I just want to set focus to newly created row.

HTML:

```
<td><input formControlName="BarCode" class="form-control" (change)="row_barCode_Change(itemrow,$event)"></td>
```

Typescript:

```
row_barCode_Change(itemRow,event){
  debugger;
  let itemRow_FormGroup= itemRow as FormGroup;
  let barCode = itemRow_FormGroup.value.BarCode;
         this.addNewRow();

         }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187302/how-do-you-programmatically-focus-on-a-column-row-in-ngx-datatable/50189278#50189278, well, thinking about the answer, perhafs the variable "adding" is unnecesary

Comment: Thanks its working . But why variable adding is unnecessary. Is any other way?

Comment: Really this.childChildren.changes shouldn't happens else we add a row or when we remove it, if only add rows, we needn't use the variable.